# Not able to see Publications after upgrading CM

Tags: web8.5

I am upgrading Tridion 2013 CMS to SDL Web 8.5. After Installation of Web 8.5 and upgrading databases I have added a new user as Administrator in the `Trustee` table and was able to login with that user. Surprisingly, I can't see any Publications in CME. Can anyone please suggest the obvious issues.

Comment: Things change. Admin rights are not set like that anymore. On mobile, so won't put a link, but it is documented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add the user to the "SDL Web Content Manager Administrators" group instead of changing the old "Privilege" column in the database. That mechanism is no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks Peter, trick worked for me. I have assigned "SDL Web Content Manager Administrators" to the newly created user and it started showing the publications.